# Crashing while trying to save CoreData ManageddObject

Tags: core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a crash while trying to save CoreData managed object like this:

```
func saveRide(rideDetails details: Ride)  {
        
        
   if managedContext != nil {
            
    let ride = RideDetails(context: managedContext!)
    ride.rideId =  details.rideId
    ride.avgSpeed = Int64(details.avgSpeed ?? 0)
    ride.blindSpotLeft = Int64(details.blindSpotLeft ?? 0)
    ride.blindSpotRight = Int64(details.blindSpotRight ?? 0)
    ride.distance = details.distance ?? 0.0
    ride.distanceKeeping = Int64(details.distanceKeeping ?? 0)
    ride.forwardCollision =  Int64(details.forwardCollision ?? 0)
    ride.maxAngle = details.maxAngle ?? 0.0
    ride.maxSpeed = details.maxSpeed ?? 0.0
            
    var locations :[LocationDetails] = []
    for locationDetails in details.locations {
                
      let location = LocationDetails(context: managedContext!)
      
      location.lat = locationDetails.lat ?? 0.0
      location.lon = locationDetails.lon ?? 0.0
      location.ride = ride
      
      locations.append(location)
    }
            
    if locations.count > 0 {
                
     let locationsSet = NSOrderedSet(array: locations)
     ride.addToLocations(locationsSet)
    }
            
    do {
          try self.managedContext?.save()
    }
    catch let error {
          
      self.delegate?.didFailuredToCompleteTheOperation?(message: error.localizedDescription)
      #if DEBUG
      print("Failed to save:\(error)")
      #endif
    }
      
   }
```

The error message I get in the console is

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'**

The managed object is:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(RideDetails)
public class RideDetails: NSManagedObject {

}

//
//  RideDetails+CoreDataProperties.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Maria Davidenko on 13/04/2021.
//
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension RideDetails {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<RideDetails> {
        return NSFetchRequest<RideDetails>(entityName: "RideDetails")
    }

    @NSManaged public var avgSpeed: Int64
    @NSManaged public var blindSpotLeft: Int64
    @NSManaged public var blindSpotRight: Int64
    @NSManaged public var distance: Float
    @NSManaged public var distanceKeeping: Int64
    @NSManaged public var forwardCollision: Int64
    @NSManaged public var maxAngle: Float
    @NSManaged public var maxSpeed: Float
    @NSManaged public var rideId: String?
    @NSManaged public var timestamp: Date?
    @NSManaged public var locations: NSOrderedSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for locations
extension RideDetails {

    @objc(insertObject:inLocationsAtIndex:)
    @NSManaged public func insertIntoLocations(_ value: LocationDetails, at idx: Int)

    @objc(removeObjectFromLocationsAtIndex:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromLocations(at idx: Int)

    @objc(insertLocations:atIndexes:)
    @NSManaged public func insertIntoLocations(_ values: [LocationDetails], at indexes: NSIndexSet)

    @objc(removeLocationsAtIndexes:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromLocations(at indexes: NSIndexSet)

    @objc(replaceObjectInLocationsAtIndex:withObject:)
    @NSManaged public func replaceLocations(at idx: Int, with value: LocationDetails)

    @objc(replaceLocationsAtIndexes:withLocations:)
    @NSManaged public func replaceLocations(at indexes: NSIndexSet, with values: [LocationDetails])

    @objc(addLocationsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToLocations(_ value: LocationDetails)

    @objc(removeLocationsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromLocations(_ value: LocationDetails)

    @objc(addLocations:)
    @NSManaged public func addToLocations(_ values: NSOrderedSet)

    @objc(removeLocations:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromLocations(_ values: NSOrderedSet)

}

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(LocationDetails)
public class LocationDetails: NSManagedObject {

}

import Foundation
import CoreData


extension LocationDetails {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<LocationDetails> {
        return NSFetchRequest<LocationDetails>(entityName: "LocationDetails")
    }

    @NSManaged public var lat: Double
    @NSManaged public var lon: Double
    @NSManaged public var ride: RideDetails?

}
```

My guess is that relationship does it, but I never worked with a relationship in CoreData before (only in RDBMS) so I'm struggling to fix it. If anyone has idea how to fix it, please,help, this is bug production.
Thanks in advance,
Maria.

Comment: Tip: add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: NowI've started to get Failed to save:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133010 "Cannot save objects with references outside of their own stores."